# multiple SQL insertion & form validation In php

Tags: php, mysql, validation, insertion

I am trying to do multiple product add with a form using php and mysql , and i am confusing on the concept of doing these,

My expecting output is , provide a form with at least ten rows of multiple field to be fill and do the validation among these , and proceed to insertion if no error .

Here is what i understand about single form insertion so far:

```
    $add_errors = array();

//if there is a post request
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 

// do some validation
if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $add_errors['name'] = 'Please enter the name!';
}

if (empty($_POST['description'])) {
        $add_errors['description'] = 'Please enter the description!';
}

if (empty($add_errors)) { // If everything's OK.
//do the insertion
$q = 'INSERT INTO ........')';
}

}//end of form submission


echo '<form action="product_add.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">';
echo '<input type=..... name=...... id=.....>';
echo '<input type=..... name=...... id=.....>';
echo '<input type=..... name=...... id=.....>';
echo '</form';
//this form is only a single row with multiple column(field) ,I am trying to make it into multiple column
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite the above code...I'm going to rewrite it here:

```
<?php
$rows = 10; // rows desired.

//if there is a post request
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 

    while($i < $rows){
        if (empty($_POST['description'.$i])) {
        $add_errors['description'.$i] = 'Please enter the description!';
        }
        // more error checking if needed...
        ++$i;
    }

    if (empty($add_errors)) { // If everything's OK.
        //do the insertion
        $q = 'INSERT INTO ........')';
    }

}//end of form submission

echo '<form action="product_add.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">';
$i = 0;
while($i < $rows){
    echo '<input type=..... name="description'.$i.'" id=.....>';
    ++$i;
}
echo '</form';
?>
```

Try something like that...(my code might have an error or two in it as I just wrote it here and didn't test it) but that's the general idea. =)

Comment: Thanks guys for pointing me to the right direction . I think i probably get your general idea =)